How to handle repeated events in a time range intersection calculation in Pandas?
I am working on a Python script using Pandas to analyze event data. My goal is to calculate the intersection of active events.
My code works fine if the same event doesn't happen twice. However, if it happens twice, my code returns empty dataframes.
Here it is the defective code:
import pandas as pd
def is_active(df, event, start_date, end_date):
        """Filters events that are active within a time range."""
        filter = (df['event_name'] == event) & (
            (df['start_date'] <= end_date) & (df['end_date'] >= start_date)
        )
        return df[filter].shape[0] > 0

def is_not_active(df, event, start_date, end_date):
    """Filters events that are inactive within a time range."""
    filter = (df['event_name'] == event) & (
        (df['start_date'] <= end_date) & (df['end_date'] >= start_date)
    )
    return df[filter].empty

def generate_active_intersection(df_events, active_events, inactive_events, combination):
    """Generates a DataFrame with active events and filters inactive ones."""
    # Define initial intersection range as the maximum start_date and minimum end_date among active events
    df_filtered = df_events[df_events['event_name'].isin(active_events)]
    
    if df_filtered.empty:
        return pd.DataFrame()  # No common active events
    
    max_start_date = df_filtered['start_date'].max()
    min_end_date = df_filtered['end_date'].min()
    
    # Ensure the time range is valid
    if max_start_date > min_end_date:
        return pd.DataFrame()  # No overlap of all active events
    
    # Verify that there is a temporal intersection among all active events
    for event in active_events:
        if not is_active(df_events, event, max_start_date, min_end_date):
            return pd.DataFrame()  # No overlap of all active events
        
    # Verify that inactive events are NOT active in the same time range
    for inactive_event in inactive_events:
        event_without_no = inactive_event.replace("NO_", "")
        if not is_not_active(df_events, event_without_no, max_start_date, min_end_date):
            return pd.DataFrame()  # Some event that should be inactive is active

    # Calculate active time in seconds
    active_time_seconds = (min_end_date - max_start_date).total_seconds()
    
    # If all conditions are met, return the common time range with the catalog format
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'start_date': [max_start_date],
        'end_date': [min_end_date],
        'catalog': [combination],  # Use the original catalog combination
        'active_time_seconds': [active_time_seconds]
    })

def process_catalog(df_events, df_catalog):
    """Processes each catalog combination and generates the corresponding DataFrames."""
    results = []
    
    for index, row in df_catalog.iterrows():
        combination = row['catalog']
        events = combination.split(', ')
        
        active_events = [e for e in events if not e.startswith('NO_')]
        inactive_events = [e for e in events if e.startswith('NO_')]
        
        df_result = generate_active_intersection(df_events, active_events, inactive_events, combination)
        
        if not df_result.empty:
            results.append(df_result)
    
    if results:
        return pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(columns=['start_date', 'end_date', 'catalog', 'active_time_seconds'])  # No valid results

The sample data is here:
# Example DataFrames:
events = pd.DataFrame({
    'event_name': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'start_date': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-10-01 09:45:00', 
        '2023-10-01 12:00:00', 
        '2023-10-02 14:30:00', 
        '2023-10-04 16:00:00', 
        '2023-10-05 18:15:00',
        '2023-10-05 18:20:00'
    ]),
    'end_date': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-10-03 11:30:00', 
        '2023-10-05 18:00:00', 
        '2023-10-06 23:59:59', 
        '2023-10-07 08:45:00', 
        '2023-10-08 20:00:00',
        '2023-10-08 10:00:00',
    ])
})
candidates = pd.DataFrame({
    'catalog': ['A, B, C', 'B, C, D', 'A, NO_E, C']
})
# Process and get the results
df_results = process_catalog(events, candidates)
print(f"Catalog results with start_time, end_time, name and active time in seconds: \n", df_results, "\n")

The code works fine as it is, but if you change the last "F" for an "A" in "event_name", the whole thing fails and the function returns an empty dataframe as a result.

What do you want the function to do if the same event has multile rows in the dataframe? Also, as a side note, it's recommended that you don't shadow built-in Python function names like filter.

"My goal is to calculate the intersection of active events". How? Please explain in words what steps / calculations are necessary to reach the desired result, and also add that exact desired output based on samples provided. E.g., you mention that your code fails if "A" occurs more than once in "event_name". Please show us the expected output for that use case, and the steps (in words) deemed necessary to reach that output. Asking (in effect): "my code does not work -- please help" does not meet SO guidelines. Please see [ask].

It's unclear what the expected output is in cases of same event is. However, if you are trying to get total active event time as a cumulative total,
the issue might stem from the fact that you're checking whether max_start_date is greater than min_end_date. This could lead to a logical error, especially if events overlap partially or completely. In such cases, your current code might return an empty dataframe when it shouldn't.
Instead of this:
    max_start_date = df_filtered['start_date'].max()
    min_end_date = df_filtered['end_date'].min()
    
    # Ensure the time range is valid
    if max_start_date > min_end_date:
        return pd.DataFrame()  # No overlap of all active events

Perhaps you want something like this:

    min_start_date = df_filtered['start_date'].min()
    max_end_date = df_filtered['end_date'].max()

    # Ensure the time range is valid
    if min_start_date > max_end_date:
        return pd.DataFrame()  # No overlap of all active events

